# After configmap configures java_opts parameters,k8s always reports wrong parameters；

Tags: kubernetes, java-opts

- kubernetes version: 1.18.6
- Dockerfile jdk:1.8_231
- Dockerfile content:

```
FROM harbor.testcbi.com/base/centos-jdk8-ast
MAINTAINER dailiang<dailiang666666@gmail.com>
WORKDIR /data
COPY  cbp-user-1.0.0.jar /data/
COPY  bootstrap.properties /data/
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","core-us-1.0.0.jar"]
```

ConfigMap yaml content:

[image]

my deployment yaml:

[image]

logs:

```
[root@master01 ~]# kubectl logs core-us-deployment-6b784c8d96-b9z8b

Improperly specified VM option 'InitialHeapSize=1024m -XX:MaxHeapSize=1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=84m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=240m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

and when I change the jvm args to `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m;` Got the following error

```
[root@master01 ~]# kubectl logs core-us-deployment-6b784c8d96-krfhg
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=84m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=240m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I have googled for a long time, but I still haven’t found the answer. Please help me！！！！

Comment: Could you try to do that in your pod as env variable? There is an example on [banzaicloud](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/java10-container-sizing/).  Additionally take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645367/11977760), might be related to your issue.

Comment: if I changed -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m , to => -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M ,Still get the same error； if I only a parameter -XX:MaxHeapSize=1024m,it started woking!!!

Comment: my configmap core-us-map: '''apiVersion: v1 data: JAVA_OPTS: -XX:MaxHeapSize=1024m ''' it started working,But this is not what i need

Comment: @Jakub
If I set the parameters of the command in the following way, the pod can start normally：

command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - java $(JAVA_OPTS) -jar /data/core-us-1.0.0.jar
````
if i remove "sh -c",pod will not start normally；As follows:
````
command:
    - java
    - $JAVA_OPTS
    - -jar
    - core-us-1.0.0..jar
````
why???????